# What style of programming is this called?

Tags: coding-style, terminology

I don't have good name for this style of programming where the syntax is 
*more* succinct because of not having to pass the context into a function or call the functions off of a context object.

For example, some random OpenGL C code:

```
 glBegin(GL_QUADS);
 glNormal3fv(&n[i][0]);
 glVertex3fv(&v[faces[i][0]][0]);
 glVertex3fv(&v[faces[i][1]][0]);
 glVertex3fv(&v[faces[i][2]][0]);
 glVertex3fv(&v[faces[i][3]][0]);
 glEnd();
```

But you could set the context in the "begin" call and release it in the "end" call.
I have seen styles like this in C#, Java, and Ruby. Does it have a name?

Comment: The reason I ask - is when I think about building internal DSLs - the functionality to not mention the context repeatedly is quite handy.

Comment: VB.NET has the With statement. Ruby has a few techniques to minimize specifying the context over and over. I just thought this might have a name.

Comment: I realize C code is not the best to demonstrate. The Ruby on Rails - Active Record migrations syntax for create_table has this nature to it. Only specifies the context once. http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyonrails/a/migrations.htm

Comment: You could look at using a fluent interface, where every method returns an instance of the object itself.  It's a much better approach: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Comment: I agree the Fluent Interface is great for programmers. But what if you want to mask the context because its more a Business Analyst that will be using your language as a DSL.

Answer (score 6):

**"Procedural with global-state side-effects"**?

(While OGL does use a stack to maintain various state, it is not used in this example and thus omitted from my reply.)

Comment: I like where you are going on this +1. Is this some of the popMatrix / pushMatrix stuff is doing in OpenGL? What do you think about my Ruby comment at the question level? It uses a closure.

Answer (score 1):

Reference oriented programming?

Comment: Is that a real name? I kind of like it. maybe Implied Reference or Implied Context. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you assume there is a "this" in front of the statements you could consider it a Fluent interface: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Otherwise, it appears very much like a Stack-Oriented language such as PostScript:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-oriented_programming_language

Comment: Not really, a fluent interface is about being able to directly continue the operation by invoking a method of the result of the previous method. This snippet of code does do something entirely different.

Comment: Yes, when you assume that there is a "this" in front of these calls.

Comment: @Nissan Then it just looks like bad Java :-)

Comment: Good answer and references. +1 I would agree that it is sort of like a twist on the Fluent idea. And I should have thought about the Stack. Good 1.

Answer (score 1):

It seems very similar to a *Builder*

Answer (score 1):

This looks sorta like a builder. What you have there is openGL calls and you are basically constructing a triangle (that is rendered). Your example rewritten in oo/builder terms:

```
TriangleBuilder b = new TriangleBuilder();
b.AddVertex(normal, faces[0]);
b.AddVertex(normal, faces[1]);
b.AddVertex(normal, faces[2]);
Triangle t = b.Build();
```

Comment: +1. I see what you are talking about... it's like a Builder but is hiding the "b" (or current context). This pattern could be used for things other than Building things... so I'm not sure Builder would always convey the right idea.

Comment: @ B. Tyndall: I agree, that's why I wrote "This looks sorta like ..." instead of "This is ..."